# How can I add attributes to a section in a GNU linker script?

Tags: linker, gnu, ld, linker-scripts

I'm doing a deep-dive into the linker scripts as understood by the GNU linker.

I am wondering if it is possible to make the linker add section flags (such as READONLY, and LOAD) to an output section.

The closest thing in the manual of ld is the "Output Section Type", but if I understand correctly the directives mentioned there (NOLOAD and DSECT/COPY/INFO/OVERLAY) can only remove section flags, not add them.